# Angular8 and Full Calendar component

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, angular8, fullcalendar-4

I am trying to make full calendar working in my Angular8 application. I tried few different ways of implementation but all let me down so far.
Most tutorials and examples suggests to use "jquery approach" but I think it is outdated, when I tried it, something like this:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar(
            this.defaultConfigurations
        );
```

I have an runtime error that fullCalendar is not a function.

The only way I could make calendar to work is this approach:

```
export class EventCalendarViewComponent extends BaseClass implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('calendar', null) calendar: FullCalendarComponent;

calendarPlugins = [dayGridPlugin];
calendarEvents = [];
addDialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddEventComponent>;
editDialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditEventComponent>;

constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, protected snackBar: MatSnackBar, private eventService: EventService) {
    super(snackBar);
}

protected getData() {
    this.eventService.getAllEvents().subscribe(res => {
        res.forEach(event => {
            const calendarEvent: CalendarEvent = this.schoolEventToCalendarEvent(event);
            this.calendarEvents.push(calendarEvent);
        });
    });
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData();
}

private schoolEventToCalendarEvent(event: SchoolEvent): CalendarEvent {
    return {
        id: event.id,
        title: event.title,
        start: moment(event.startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        end: moment(event.endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    }
} ...
```

and html looks like this then:

```
<full-calendar #calendar
               defaultView="dayGridMonth"
               [plugins]="calendarPlugins"
               [events]="calendarEvents"
               [editable]="true"
               [allDayDefault]="true"
               [timeZone]="'local'"
></full-calendar>
```

However events populates with getData() method do not show on the calendar. The only way to see any events is static population of its variable:

```
calendarEvents = [{id: 1, title: 'static entry', start: '2019-09-05'}];
```

What is the trick here? I cannot find the way to refresh the calendar after db call is comleted.

Comment: Are you doing this using the [Angular Component](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular) provided by fullCalendar? It's not 100% clear from your description.

Comment: Well, I think it is clear, I have this at the top: @ViewChild('calendar', null) calendar: FullCalendarComponent;

Comment: However my component work (show the calendar) even without ViewChild declaration, it doesn't matter it is there or not. There only issue is that it doesn't show new events added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the trick is (at least in my case) to declare the component like this:

```
<full-calendar #calendar
               defaultView="dayGridMonth"
               deepChangeDetection="true"
               [plugins]="calendarPlugins"
               [events]="calendarEvents"
               [refetchResourcesOnNavigate]="true"
               [editable]="true"
               [allDayDefault]="true"
               [timeZone]="'local'"
></full-calendar>
```

So I think that

> deepChangeDetection="true"

is the the property which make the difference.
refetchResourcesOnNavigate which is there as well do not change anything. Since my data comes from the the database another property:

> rerenderDelay

might be useful here, especially that deepChangeDetection might affect the performance.